# Does separate graphics card has an impact on number of RAM slots supported on motherboard

Tags: memory, integrated-graphics

As we all know that graphics card can be found integrated/in-built on the motherboard or can be additional/separated which is plugged into some slot (I believe PCI slot) on motherboard.

My question is that, *does the graphics card be it integrated/additional somehow limits the number of RAM slots provisioned on the motherboard due to some hardware architecture they follow or may be because graphics card and RAM has to work coherently*?

I'm observing that in the new laptops that are coming from various manufacturers generally have ONLY one RAM slot. So if I've to expand the RAM memory I've to let go of the existing memory stick and replace it with a memory stick of higher capacity. I just can't place another memory stick in parallel.

*I just want to know whether it is additional graphics card or any other reason which generally limits the number of RAM slots on motherboard? Does performance fall too much if computer has to deal with 2 RAM slots in place of 1*?

Comment: No. Correlation does not imply causation. Just because manufacturers are being cheap and only providing one ram slot doesn't mean that integrated graphics is to blame. Many recent laptops I've seen have one ram slot on the underside of the machine, and another hidden under the keyboard. Cheaper laptops may well have only one slot.

Comment: As it was already pointed out there is no correlation. In addition laptops are usually quite different from desktops as the space is way more limited and they're usually more targeted and just don't allow as much customization to keep the price low. Your italics aren't really helping the readability of your questions, a line break/paragraph would've been better IMHO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Graphics cards and the physical number of RAM slots are completely independent of each other.  Simply put, there is *no* relationship between the two.

You say, "I'm observing that in the new laptops that are coming from various manufacturers generally have ONLY one RAM slot."  This is not something that I have noticed, or even looked for.  It may be true.  If it is, in my opinion, this is most likely due to keeping manufacturing costs down.  The cost of a RAM slot might cost only pennies, but when you manufacture millions of laptops, pennies add up.  That coupled with the fact that the amount of RAM users require has not changed much in while, the need for an additional slot of RAM becomes unnecessary.

You ask, "Does performance fall too much if computer has to deal with 2 RAM slots in place of 1?" The answer to this is no.  Generally speaking, the more sticks of RAM a computer has, the better it will perform.  This is due to a technology called [memory interleaving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interleaved_memory).  Memory interleaving means that two 4GB sticks of RAM will be faster than one 8GB stick, assuming they are the same in every way, except capacity.

To reiterate the main question, the amount of memory slots available has *nothing* to do with the other hardware on the motherboard.